# Hacer sumatoria en una columna de un arreglo o matriz en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

quisiera saber si existe una forma de realizar una sumatoria de una columna en un arreglo, utilizando algún método integrado en las librería de C#, como por ejemplo Math.sum(), sin tener que realizar un cilco.
Debajo una imagen y el código, el cual realiza la sumatoria de la columna número 0, dando una sumatoria de 14.
Saludos

[image: Arreglo]

```
        double[,] arreglo_2 = new double[3, 2];
        double sumatoria=0;

        arreglo_2[0, 0] = 2; arreglo_2[0, 1] = 350;
        arreglo_2[1, 0] = 5; arreglo_2[1, 1] = 210;
        arreglo_2[2, 0] = 7; arreglo_2[2, 1] = 600;

        i = 0;
        while (i < 3)
        {                               
            sumatoria += info_pieza[i, 0];
         
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: si, con sum y linq.. pero no ganas absolutamente nada

Comment: Gracias, podrias poner un pequeño ejemplo si no es mucha molestia.

Comment: Porque no utilizar un ciclo bro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor implementacion que pude encontrar implica realizar una extension

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[,] arreglo_2 = new double[3, 2];

        arreglo_2[0, 0] = 2; arreglo_2[0, 1] = 350;
        arreglo_2[1, 0] = 5; arreglo_2[1, 1] = 210;
        arreglo_2[2, 0] = 7; arreglo_2[2, 1] = 600;
        
        var itemsCol0 = arreglo_2.GetColumn(0);
        double sumCol0 = itemsCol0.Sum();
    
        var itemsCol1 = arreglo_2.GetColumn(1);
        double sumCol1 = itemsCol1.Sum();
    
    
        Console.WriteLine("Sum Col0: {0}, Col1: {1}", sumCol0, sumCol1);
    }
    

}

public static class ArrayExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> GetColumn(this double[,] array, int column)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            yield return array[i, column];
        }
    }
}
```

La idea de la extension es poder obtener los valores de una columna y despues sumarlos

Me base en lo que se comenta aqui

[LINQ Multi Dimesnional array](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8e9ee18-07aa-4f62-9dd1-e2341cd94b85/linq-multi-dimesnional-array?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Gracias @LeandroTuttini, se ve interesante esta forma. Pero Visualstudio me muestra error en GetColumn(); con la siguiente descripion: 
Error CS1061 "double[*,*]" no contiene una definición para "GetColumn" ni un método de extensión accesible "GetColumn" que acepte un primer argumento del tipo "double[*,*]" (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Utilice las mismas librerias que utilizas

Comment: El GetColumn() esta en una extension, debes ponerlo en una class static separada https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

no se puede usar linq contra un array multidimensional...

asi que hay que transformar tu array a uno simple..

y luego hacer la suma.. nada que te sirva realmente, pero aca va:

```
double[,] arreglo_2 = new double[3, 2];

arreglo_2[0, 0] = 2; arreglo_2[0, 1] = 350;
arreglo_2[1, 0] = 5; arreglo_2[1, 1] = 210;
arreglo_2[2, 0] = 7; arreglo_2[2, 1] = 600;

var query = from double item in arreglo_2
    where item % 2 != 0
    select item;
Console.WriteLine(query.Sum());
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, lo probe devuel un valor de 12, deberia ser 14, para este caso.